# Perl script is sending mail very slow via sendmail - one mail every 30 seconds

Tags: sendmail

I have a perl script that sends mail out to a mailing list.

On my old dedicated server, it worked fine, and sent one email per second basically. I recently switched to a new dedicated server, with about the same specs, and it's going extremely slow, about one mail every 30 seconds. I set up a test script to watch what part takes the longest:

```
open(MAIL,"| /usr/sbin/sendmail -tv -d8.7 $recipient_email");
print MAIL <<EOF;
From:Test Sender <$sender>
To:$recipient_email
Subject:Testing

Justw ant to see how long this takes

EOF
close(MAIL);
```

The -d8.7 there is a debug option that lets me watch the output of the script. I will paste that here, there are 3 spots which both hang for too long, I will mark them here:

```
dns_getcanonname(receiving_server.com, trymx=1)

dns_getcanonname: trying receiving_server.com. (A)
```

**5 second delay here**
        YES

```
dns_getcanonname: receiving_server.com

getmxrr([127.0.0.1], droplocalhost=1)

andrew@receiving_server.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...

220 my_server.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.13.8/8.13.8; Fri, 18 May 2012 06:55:04 +0200

>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain

250-my_server.com Hello localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you

250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

250-PIPELINING

250-8BITMIME

250-SIZE

250-DSN

250-ETRN

250-DELIVERBY

250 HELP

>>> MAIL From:<root@localhost.localdomain> SIZE=115
```

**10 second delay here**

```
250 2.1.0 <root@localhost.localdomain>... Sender ok

>>> RCPT To:<andrew@receiving_server.com>

>>> DATA
```

**5 second delay here**

```
250 2.1.5 <andrew@receiving_server.com>... Recipient ok

354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself

>>> .

250 2.0.0 q4I4t4Lu014501 Message accepted for delivery

andrew@receiving_server.com... Sent (q4I4t4Lu014501 Message accepted for delivery)

Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]

>>> QUIT

221 2.0.0 my_server.com closing connection
```

As far as I can tell, my /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf seem fine, and these are the only things that Google suggests might be broken, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like

1. Delay to resolve name via DNS
2. Recipient check by remote SMTP server
3. Sender check by remote SMTP server

Is the remote server the same as before? Do you have any visibility of that server?

Have you run tcpdump on that interface to see if there is any protocol activity during the gaps? Try this (as root) -

```
# tcpdump -vvv -w output.pcap -i eth0 'port not 22'
```

This will capture all traffic except your SSH session traffic and output to the file 'output.pcap'.

I don't suppose there's any chance you've moved to an IP that is on a blacklist somewhere? Sites like the following can help you find out -

http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Comment: This is the same across multiple different remote SMTP servers - Gmail, Hotmail, a bunch of university servers, all of them have the same delay on step 2. Also the DNS delay seems to happen no matter what DNS servers I put in (my providers, or ones I have on another server). I have to figure out the tcpdump thing, I'm not very good at sysadminning, I'll look that up, thanks!

Comment: No problem! I'll put a command in the answer for tcpdump.

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to know how quickly 'dig g.co' returns on your server - it's a dns lookup which will use the servers in /etc/resolv.conf.

Comment: 109 msec for the g.co thing.. I have used nslookup to look up a bunch of servers and they're all similarly fast. I'll go run the tcpdump stuff and whatnot, thanks!

Comment: Ahh, I am on 6 blacklists. I will look into getting off those, but in the meantime, would that actually slow things down? I mean, I understand it would for some servers, but do you think ALL the servers are checking those lists? Cause it's literally this slow on every single one I sent to - AOL, prodigy, msn, hotmail, etc etc etc. Oh yeah, I actually just tried sending to a server I have somewhere else, and it's slow to that too, and I know it doesn't check any lists.

Comment: also want to clarify: The lists are from whoever had this IP before me, none of my mail is spammy in the LEAST (just wanna make sure that is clear, since I am, after all, asking about sending a lot of email, and then saying I am on blacklists, which seems fishy).

Comment: When connecting to your server are the delays *exactly* the same? In the interests of excluding what you can, I'd get the blacklist issue fixed asap. Possibly by asking your ISP to give you a clean IP.